# How to avoid node:12044 Error : data and salt arguments required?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I tried out few tricks to avoid this error but without luck-

*(node:12044) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: data and salt arguments required
at hash (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:137:17)
at D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:29:12
at new Promise ()
at Object.module.exports.promise (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:20:12)
at hash (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:133:25)
at createUser (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\api\users\user.controller.js:8:21)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
(node:12044) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12044) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
')' at line 1
at Query.Sequence._packetToError (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
at Query.ErrorPacket (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:79:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
at Parser._parsePacket (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
at Parser.write (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
at Protocol.write (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
at Socket. (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
at Socket. (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
--------------------
at Pool.query (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:199:23)
at create (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\api\users\user.service.js:5:14)
at createUser (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\api\users\user.controller.js:9:9)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (D:\Coding_Challenge\Challenge-solution\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10) {
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
errno: 1064,
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1",
sqlState: '42000',
index: 0,
sql: 'Insert into registration (firstname,lastname,email,pass) values (NULL, NULL, NULL, )'
}*

The code that I have is :-

```
const { create } =require("./user.service");
const {genSalt,hash} = require("bcrypt");
module.exports = {
    createUser: (req,res) => {
        const body=req.body;
        const salt=genSalt(10);
        body.pass = hash(body.pass,salt);
        create(body,(err,results) => {
             if(err){
                 console.log(err);
                 return res.status(500).json({
                     success: 0,
                     message: "Database connection error"
                 });
             }
             return res.status(200).json({
                 success:1,
                 data:results
             });
        });
    }
}
```

In the service.js I have :-

```
const pool= require("../../config/database");

module.exports={
    create: (data,callBack) => {
        pool.query(
            
            `Insert into registration (firstname,lastname,email,pass) values (?, ?, ?, ?)`,
            [
              data.firstname,
              data.lastname,
              data.email,
              data.pass
            ],
            (error,results,fields) => {
                if(error){
                   return callBack(error)
                }
                return callBack(null,results)
            }
        );
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) the `genSalt` and `hash` functions do not return the results directly, but in a callback. Thus, your call `const salt = genSalt(10)` sets `salt` to `undefined`. And that's why the `hash` function complains about a missing salt.

So the correct usage is as follows

```
genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  hash(body.pass, salt, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    body.pass = hash;
    ...
  }
});
```

Alternatively you can also use the sync versions `genSaltSync` and `hashSync`  as follows

```
const salt = getSaltSync(10);
const hash = hashSync(body.pass, salt);
```

Comment: I tried both the above mentioned solutions. Unfortunately the error is again "Error: data and salt arguments required" fot he first solution usage

Comment: does `body.pass` exist and does it have a value?

Comment: body.pass is showing as undefined in the console.... I have followed your 1st solution

Comment: well if `body.pass` is undefined, it's no wonder, the `hash` function complains about missing data ...